# Node error, can't set up localhost to test React applications **SOLVED** .env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I am facing a real issue trying to run any react application, my node always trow errors. My goal is to set up this project to a localhost:8000 so I can test it.

this is my package.json.

```js
{
  "name": "cr-surf-forecast",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I have already erased the .lock and tried to reinstall the dependencies, same error, I will repeat. I am now erasing node_mudules folder and doing npm install & npm start. The npm install gives no error, but once I try to npm start, an error happens, as below.

```js
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
PS C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\surf-forecasting-app-master> npm start

> cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\surf-forecasting-app-master
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

[ED. TRANSLATION: 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal
command or external, an operable program or a batch file.]

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-26T17_09_00_453Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\surf-forecasting-app-master>
```

This is the error log created when I run npm start:

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Dev\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0~prestart: cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0~start: cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\surf-forecasting-app-master\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\iCLS\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\iCLS\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\DAL\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\DAL\;C:\Program Files\Intel\TXE Components\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\TXE Components\IPT\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\surf-forecasting-app-master
10 silly lifecycle cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\surf-forecasting-app-master
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Dev\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.5
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the cr-surf-forecast@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I am lost, I saw node.js working once with a huge project (1gb of node_modules), but I am starting to think that is a Computer issue, I am using a Samsung flash laptop with windows 10 home, can you guys help me? Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED ***

Everybody facing the same issue should try:

The one that solved mine was the last: **add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file** in your project

```js
o fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "webpack-dev-server" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if c:\Users\Dev\node_modules\webpack-dev-server is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls webpack-dev-server in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack-dev-server.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

PS C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\surf-forecasting-app-master> node c:\Users\Dev\Desktop\surf-forecasting-app-master\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
Starting the development server...
Compiled with warnings.
```

OK LOCALHOST:8000 DONE